# In threejs How to create spheres with increasing radius but passing through same point say (0,0,200)

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do I create spheres in threejs with increasing radius but passing through one unique point 0,0,200, effectively moving the origin of new sphere along z axis.

Thank you,
AriemWebgl

Answer (score 4):

Create an "parent" Object3D and attach the spheres to it; when you move the parent, the attached objects will move together.

```
var sphereParent = new THREE.Object3D();
var numSpheres = 8;
for(var i = 0 ; i < numSpheres; i++)
{
   var radius = 10 + i;
   var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 16, 8 );
   var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
   var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial );
   sphereParent.add( sphere );
}
sphereParent.position.set(0,0,200);
scene.add(sphereParent);
```

Comment: I am trying to create convex mirror with changing radius on user input but it should not lose its position. lets say first we create sphere mirror with (0,0,0) origin of 80 radius. (0,0,80) is point on sphere where camera is looking at.  On user input I want to increase the radius to 100 and shift the origin to (0,0,-20) so that sphere still passes through 0,0,80. Tried using scale.x, scale.y and scale.z and re- setting position to z-delta; no getting expected result.

Comment: I could achieve the desired result by removing the sphere and re-adding it. Ex. If I increase radius by 10 units, I move the zposition -10. But this seems to be too slow. How can I achieve the same with scale and position adjustment. What is the relation between sphere.scale.x+=0.01 to radius increase? ideally there should be scale.radius.

Comment: Did I answer the question that you asked?  If so, accept the answer, if not, tell me why not and I may try again.  However, if you have a new question, create an entirely new post.

Comment: No. The answer provided by you creates concentric spheres. I am looking for solution in which the spheres are touching internally at one fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's just a matter of creating a few meshes and changing they're position:

```
var numSpheres = 8;
for(var i = 0 ; i < numSpheres; i++){
   var radius = 10 + (5*i);//increase the radius based the counter
   var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 26, 18 ), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, overdraw: true, wireframe:true } ) );
   sphere.position.z = 200;//or sphere.position.set(0,0,200);
   scene.add( sphere );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an ancient question probably solved a long time ago, but since it's not answered, for future readers...

The number of spheres of radius `R` with a common surface point `P` is equal to the `4πR²` surface area of a sphere of radius `R` centered at `P`, since their centers are themselves points on a `P` centered sphere surface:

[image: Common Point Spheres]

In the case from this question though, where internally tangent spheres are involved, math shows that the center of the updated sphere (`C₁`) will be on the direction between the common point (`P`) and the center of the original sphere (`C₀`), at a distance equal to their radius difference (`R₁ - R₀`) from the latter (`C₀`):

[image: Internally Tangent Spheres]

When it comes to positional and directional vectors, we need to know that, generally speaking:

- *to translate a position by a distance along a direction we add the product of direction and distance to it*
- *a direction between two positions is the normalized difference between the second and the first position*

So, `position(C₁) = position(C₀) + direction(P, C₀) * (R₁ - R₀)`, or even better, if we directly update via `position(C₀) += normalize(C₀ - P) * (R₁ - R₀)` and scale by `R₁ / R₀`, we'd write in Three.js like:

```js
sphere.position.addScaledVector(sphere.position.clone().sub(point).normalize(), newradius - oldradius);
sphere.scale.setScalar(newradius / oldradius);
```

**Note**: I used circles in the images since it was simpler, but you can think of them like cross sections through the middle of the spheres if that helps. Also, the process above will work for any point in any position, it doesn't have to be on the Z axis or even on the sphere surfaces.